# Is there an environment variable for the shell profile?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh, software-distribution

As part of an install script, I would like the users to have the option to add an environment variable to their shell's profile. i.e. for `bash`, something like

```
echo "export TOOL_DATABASE_DIR=/database/is/here >>" ~/.bash_profile
```

However, today I learned that Mac has switched to the `z` shell. Is there any way I can dynamically determine, for a current shell instance, what file is sourced as the profile?

Comment: It's not enough to know the filename, you also need to use the proper syntax for each shell. `tcsh` syntax is completely different from `bash`.

Comment: Use `$SHELL` to find out what the login shell is, and update the startup file appropriate to that shell.

Comment: @Barmar that was my original thought as well, but after reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9504/426708, I wasn't sure if there was a better way of determining the *current* shell.

Comment: Don't do that.  Tell the user which environment variables they may be interested in setting.  Let the user maintain their own dotfiles.

Comment: If you want to get a variable into user's environments, use `/etc/profile.d` (or whatever is the appropriate mechanism for the platform.  /etc/profile.d is good on linux)

Comment: As a side note, the redirection must be outside of the quotes: `echo "export FOO=bar" >> .bash_profile`; else you just echo the whole string.

Comment: @WilliamPursell but `/etc/profile.d` is owned by root, so most of our users won't have access to that. And while I agree users could maintain their own dotfiles, I was hoping to add this support in as a convenience to them.

Comment: The problem with doing that as a "convenience to your users" is that it removes your users' freedom to organize their dotfiles as they choose. For example, I often have dotfiles that have logic where they sometimes exit early (using `return`). If a program I was running automatically installed something under that guard location and didn't warn me it was doing so, I'd be annoyed.

Comment: ...similarly, one may choose to put everything in `~/.profile` and source that location from `.bash_profile` and every other possible entry point. I don't want every program I run making assumptions about how I choose to organize my dotfiles.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed, and this would be an "opt-in" convenience. But if even that idea is still frowned upon, the note is well taken and it results in less work for me anyways :p

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There are many applications whose installers offer this as an option.

Comment: All of those application's install scripts are broken.

Comment: @Barmar, agreed, but a _common_ idea and a _good_ idea are not the same thing.

Comment: @Throckmorton, have you considered, instead of using an environment variable, using a well-known config location? If `$HOME/.tool_database_dir` is expected to be a symlink to the location a user wants to use, there's nothing shell-specific that needs to be installed in the first place.

Comment: (Mind, stuffing everything in `$HOME` isn't the entirely modern ways to do things of late -- see https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html for current Linuxy guidelines on config locations, if you're targeting distros that do things the systemd-preferred way).

Comment: @Throckmorton : Not that easy. You would need to find out, what shell is running (perhaps by searching the process tree), but even if you know the shell, the files which are sourced depend on the options used on invocation of the shell, and (for instance in case of zsh and ksh) may also depend on the setting of certain environment variables (`ZDOTDIR` in zsh). Aside from this, I would consider it very rude, if someone else modified my startup files without telling me.

Comment: @Throckmorton : I suggest that you provide in some central location (`/etc` or some network share) one file for each type of shell the users may employ (zsh, fish, tcsh, .....) and ask your users to source the file from their startup directories. Then everyone can decide, where to put it.

Comment: Assuming `/etc/profile.d` is no more portable than assuming `bash` is the shell whose configuration files you want to edit. This is why the *installer* is the wrong place to be editing user configuration files. Also, `zsh` is the *default* user shell in macOS; that doesn't mean a user may not have switched back to `bash`, or switched to some other shell (like `fish`). There are simply too many options available to do anything other than tell the user which variable should be set, and leave it to them to set it appropriately.

Comment: `ps -o comm= -p $$`

Answer (score 0):

No.

You have to infer it from the $SHELL value which tells you which shell is currently configured as the login shell.

Stick your variable in ~/.zprofile and ~/.profile to cover 99.9 of your user base.

You can also find the *currently active shell using ps*, but this will not work with ubergurus who are multishellular (*who also change their shells regularly or even several times per day and never spread misinformation online. Those guys will manage to set their own variables though, you just need to cover the most typical cases*).

```bash
ps  -o comm= | sed 1q
```

Comment: okay. i have changed the wording